# C# console app for SQL Server Always encrypted operations - Azure Key Vault CMK with cert authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I want my C# console app to be able to perform SQL DML against Always-Encrypted columns in on-prem database using column master key in Azure Key Vault, and I want to Authenticate using AppId and certificate stored in my local certificate store.  I already registered the App and Service Principal, configured the cert, and assigned the permissions in Azure CLI.  I have the encryption set up, as verified in SQL Mgmt Studio.

I was able to use ODBC driver to connect and execute SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017 using both userid/pwd and interactive modes with something like this connection string:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server={instanceName};uid={myUid};trusted_connection=Yes;database={myDBName};columnencryption=Enabled;keystoreauthentication=KeyVaultPassword;keystoreprincipalid={MyADUserId};KeyStoreSecret={MyADPassword}
```

Using ODBC, there is also the option to connect with AppId/Secret in connect string, but I don't want to insert those into my app.

The last option thru ODBC is ManagedIdentity but I don't think I can use that from on-prem...  not sure.

That's why I decided upon AppId + Cert for authentication.

As POC, I can connect to the AKV and see the column master key like this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert;
string tenantId = "{my tenant id}";
string appId = "{my app id}";
string keyvaultURI = "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/";

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certs = store.Certificates;

var certFound = certs.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN={myCertSubject}",    false).OfType<X509Certificate2>();
                
if (certFound.Count() > 0)
{
   cert = certFound.Single();
   var credential = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, appId, cert);

   var client = new KeyClient(new Uri(keyvaultURI), credential);
   KeyVaultKey key = client.GetKey("MyColumnMasterKey");
   Console.WriteLine(key.Name);
   Console.WriteLine(key.KeyType);
```

The above works, though I'm not sure I'm on the right track.  What I ultimately want to do is, using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, instantiate a SQLCommand and then connect it to the AzureKeyVault for the CMK.  I don't know how to retrieve the token, though, since I need to pass in some kind of struct called "TokenRequestContext." Supposedly, I can retrieve the token from the credential I got above and connect that to the SQL column encryption using something like this:

```
var token = credential.GetToken( t ); // t is "TokenRequestContext"...  what is that???
var x = new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(token); // pass credentialToken
```

So, I can authenticate, but not quite in the way I need in order to make the jump from auth to using that in SQLCommand.

Does it look like I am on the right track here?  How can I get from the authenticated ClientCertificateCredential to the token?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` and `configuration` file.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `Azure.Identity` to create a token credential (`DefaultAzureCredential`), which simplifies token acquisition.
- Register the Azure Key Vault provider for Always Encrypted using the `SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider` with the `tokenCredential`.
- using below code i achevied  authenticate  application using the certificate and access the column master key from Azure Key Vault to enable Always Encrypted operations on your SQL Server database.

Here's the corrected code

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

       string keyVaultUrl = configuration["AzureKeyVaultUrl"];
       string columnMasterKeyName = configuration["ColumnMasterKeyName"];

        // Use Azure.Identity to create a token credential
        var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

        // Register the Azure Key Vault provider for Always Encrypted
        SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider = new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(tokenCredential);

        Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> providers = new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>();
        providers.Add(SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, azureKeyVaultProvider);

        // register the provider with ADO.net
        SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(providers);

        string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Perform SQL DML operations using Always Encrypted columns
            // Example: Insert, Update, Select with encrypted columns

            connection.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Accessed ");
    }
}
```

**Result**
[image]